# Finding the number of $2$-element chains of $B_n$

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I'm trying to calculate the number of $2$-element chains and anti-chains of $B_n$, where $B_n$ is the boolean algebra partially ordered set of degree $n$.

I understand that I want to take all of the different combinations of two sets $A$ and $B$ that are subsets of $[n]$, in which $A\subsetneq B$. But I'm not sure about the general strategy. Could any one give me some hints on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Every pair of subsets of $[n]$ is either a chain or an antichain. It’s probably a bit easier to count the chains. To form a chain $A\subsetneqq B\subseteq[n]$, you need to split $[n]$ into three subsets, $A$, $B\setminus A$, and $[n]\setminus B$. The only restriction is that $B\setminus A$ must not be empty. Imagine going through $[n]$ one element at a time, tossing each element into one of the three sets. How many ways are there to do this? How many of them have to be discarded, because they leave $B\setminus A$ empty?

Comment: Is it $S(n,3)$?

Comment: @Calc1DropOut: No, it’s much simpler than that. Here’s an equivalent question; see if it’s any easier in this form. How many $n$-letter strings of A’s, B’s, and C’s are there? How many have no B’s? (A’s correspond to members of $A$, B’s to members of $B\setminus A$, and C’s to members of $[n]\setminus B$.)

Comment: $3^n$ different strings of $A,B$ and $C$ but if we restrict that there are no $B$'s it should be $2^n$ since there are now only two choices for each $n$.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut: There you go. So there are $3^n-2^n$ that have at least one B. And that’s the number of $2$-element chains in $\wp([n])$, via the correspondence in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah! I got it now, thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: @Calc1DropOut: You’re welcome! My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: THIS IS ALL WRONG, I WAS CONFUSING THE DEFINITION OF CHAIN WITH THE EDGE ON HASSEL DIAGRAM. SILLY ME. I'LL STILL LEAVE THIS HERE SO PEOPLE WHO STUMBLED UPON THIS WILL KNOW THAT THIS IS A POSSIBLE MISTAKE.**

I am challenging @Brian M. Scott (@brian-m-scott)'s answer.

Let's take a look at $B_3$:

[image]

It has 12 2-element chains, if we plug n = 3 into $3^{n}-2^{n}$ we will get an answer of 19, which is incorrect.

By examine $B_3$, or in fact any this kind of Hasse Diagram, we will find out that at depth i (starting from 0):

Number of Nodes = $(_{i}^{n})$

Number of Edges Connecting Next Depth = $(_{n-i-1}^{n-i})$ = n-i

Thus, the total number of 2 element chains = $\sum _{i=0}^{n-i} (_{i}^{n})(n-i)$

I have tested this result with $B_3$ and $B_4$ and they are correct.

And then we can in some way write this as a closed form.

And since we have the number of 2-element chains, and like Brian said, the relationship between 2 elements are either chains or antichains. The total number of chains and antichains is $(_{2}^{n})$. So the number of antichains is $(_{2}^{n})$ minus what we got for the previous part.

Answer (score 1):

Some info for people who end up here:

The integer sequence can be found on the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C9%2C55%2C285&language=english&go=Search)

A closed form for this sequence appears in [this work](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(68)80068-7), which also has a closed form for the sequence $a_n$ = number of $3$-antichains on $B_n$. This paper is about deriving a recursive formula for the Dedekind numbers, which count the total number of antichains on $B_n$ (equivalently, the number of elements of the free distributive lattice.)

Comment: would be great if there is a summary of the link.